# How to find specific frequency of a codon?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am trying to make a function in R which could calculate the frequency of each codon.
We know that methionine is an amino acid which could be formed by only one set of codon ATG so its percentage in every set of sequence is 1. Where as Glycine could be formed by GGT, GGC, GGA, GGG hence the percentage of occurring of each codon will be 0.25.
The input would be in a DNA sequence like-ATGGGTGGCGGAGGG and with the help of codon table it could calculate the percentage of each occurrence in an input.

please help me by suggesting ways to make this function.

for example,
if my argument is ATGTGTTGCTGG
then, my result would be

```
ATG=1
TGT=0.5
TGC=0.5
TGG=1
```

---

Data for R:

```
codon <- list(ATA = "I", ATC = "I", ATT = "I", ATG = "M", ACA = "T", 
    ACC = "T", ACG = "T", ACT = "T", AAC = "N", AAT = "N", AAA = "K", 
    AAG = "K", AGC = "S", AGT = "S", AGA = "R", AGG = "R", CTA = "L", 
    CTC = "L", CTG = "L", CTT = "L", CCA = "P", CCC = "P", CCG = "P", 
    CCT = "P", CAC = "H", CAT = "H", CAA = "Q", CAG = "Q", CGA = "R", 
    CGC = "R", CGG = "R", CGT = "R", GTA = "V", GTC = "V", GTG = "V", 
    GTT = "V", GCA = "A", GCC = "A", GCG = "A", GCT = "A", GAC = "D", 
    GAT = "D", GAA = "E", GAG = "E", GGA = "G", GGC = "G", GGG = "G", 
    GGT = "G", TCA = "S", TCC = "S", TCG = "S", TCT = "S", TTC = "F", 
    TTT = "F", TTA = "L", TTG = "L", TAC = "Y", TAT = "Y", TAA = "stop", 
    TAG = "stop", TGC = "C", TGT = "C", TGA = "stop", TGG = "W")
```

Comment: It looks like your sample data is for python. Did you mean to tag that instead of R? Or (based on the text of your question) did you forget to provide an R structure for sample data?

Comment: I've suggested an edit that includes an R structure. If that is not desired, my apologies, I can remove it.

Comment: Thank you for this edit, sorry for that.

Comment: It isn't clear what the `"C"` for `"TGT"` is supposed to mean, and how this is supposed to know that you're trying to make Glycine meaning 0.25. It might help to spell-out how you calculated `TGT=0.5` (and the others) based on the structure you provided.

Comment: TGT  and TGC codes for C in DNA sequence hence probability of formation of C by TGC is 50% and for TGT is also 50%. This is same for the rest of the amino acids. This problem is based on codon usage

Comment: Do you mean that because there are two `"C"` within `codon`, that both `TGC` and `TGT` are required to make Glycine? (How the heck am I supposed to know that Glycine corresponds to `"C"`?) Does this mean that four things are needed to make `"A"`: `GCA`, `GCC`, `GCG`, and `GCT`?

Comment: Assuming that is the case, then you have two "problems" to solve: (1) translate from `list(TGT="A")` to `list(TGT=0.5)`; and (2) split a string into substrings of length 3, *assuming it is always a perfect multiple of 3*. After that, you have a perfect look-up table.

Comment: @r2evans not in a full term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I get my lookup list and sequence.

```
codon <- list(ATA = "I", ATC = "I", ATT = "I", ATG = "M", ACA = "T", 
              ACC = "T", ACG = "T", ACT = "T", AAC = "N", AAT = "N", AAA = "K", 
              AAG = "K", AGC = "S", AGT = "S", AGA = "R", AGG = "R", CTA = "L", 
              CTC = "L", CTG = "L", CTT = "L", CCA = "P", CCC = "P", CCG = "P", 
              CCT = "P", CAC = "H", CAT = "H", CAA = "Q", CAG = "Q", CGA = "R", 
              CGC = "R", CGG = "R", CGT = "R", GTA = "V", GTC = "V", GTG = "V", 
              GTT = "V", GCA = "A", GCC = "A", GCG = "A", GCT = "A", GAC = "D", 
              GAT = "D", GAA = "E", GAG = "E", GGA = "G", GGC = "G", GGG = "G", 
              GGT = "G", TCA = "S", TCC = "S", TCG = "S", TCT = "S", TTC = "F", 
              TTT = "F", TTA = "L", TTG = "L", TAC = "Y", TAT = "Y", TAA = "stop", 
              TAG = "stop", TGC = "C", TGT = "C", TGA = "stop", TGG = "W")

MySeq <- "ATGTGTTGCTGG"
```

Next, I load the `stringi` library and break the sequence into chunks of three characters.

```
# Load library
library(stringi)

# Break into 3 bases
seq_split <- stri_sub(MySeq, seq(1, stri_length(MySeq), by=3), length=3)
```

Then, I count the letters that these three base chunks correspond to using `table`.

```
# Get associated letters
letter_count <- table(unlist(codon[seq_split]))
```

Finally, I bind the sequences together with the reciprocal of the count and rename my data frame columns.

```
# Bind into a data frame
res <- data.frame(seq_split,
                  1/letter_count[match(unlist(codon[seq_split]), names(letter_count))])

# Rename columns
colnames(res) <- c("Sequence", "Letter", "Percentage")

#  Sequence Letter Percentage
#1      ATG      M        1.0
#2      TGT      C        0.5
#3      TGC      C        0.5
#4      TGG      W        1.0
```

Comment: How to get answer like you got?

Comment: @MayankSinghRajput I'm sure I understand your question. You run the code and the answer is stored in the variable `res`.

Comment: yes sir i got that, but i want to find the percentage of 64 codons only, i mean if there are 900 codons which codes for C alone than it could conclude percentage among that

Comment: @MayankSinghRajput `i want to find the percentage of 64 codons only` If you only want to consider 64 codons, then only use a list with 64 codons (like above). Or do you mean you want to get the percentage of all 64 codons even if the percentage is zero?

Comment: Yes sir i want exactly what you have said.

Answer (score 2):

Two things to solve here:

1. convert `codon` to the fractions for each letter

   ```
   ( fracs <- 1/table(unlist(codon)) )
   #         A         C         D         E         F         G         H         I 
   # 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.3333333 
   #         K         L         M         N         P         Q         R         S 
   # 0.5000000 0.1666667 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 
   #      stop         T         V         W         Y 
   # 0.3333333 0.2500000 0.2500000 1.0000000 0.5000000 
   codonfracs <- setNames(lapply(codon, function(x) unname(fracs[x])), names(codon))
   str(head(codonfracs))
   # List of 6
   #  $ ATA: num 0.333
   #  $ ATC: num 0.333
   #  $ ATT: num 0.333
   #  $ ATG: num 1
   #  $ ACA: num 0.25
   #  $ ACC: num 0.25
   ```
2. convert the sequence string to a vector of length-3 substrings

   ```
   s <- 'ATGTGTTGCTGG'

   strsplit3 <- function(s, k=3) {
     starts <- seq.int(1, nchar(s), by=k)
     stops <- c(starts[-1] - 1, nchar(s))
     mapply(substr, s, starts, stops, USE.NAMES=FALSE)
   }
   strsplit3(s)
   # [1] "ATG" "TGT" "TGC" "TGG"
   ```

From here, it's just a lookup:

```
codonfracs[ strsplit3(s) ]
# $ATG
# [1] 1
# $TGT
# [1] 0.5
# $TGC
# [1] 0.5
# $TGG
# [1] 1
```

**EDIT**

Since you want the status of the other codons, try this:

```
x <- codonfracs
x[ ! names(x) %in% strsplit3(s) ] <- 0
str(x)
# List of 64
#  $ ATA: num 0
#  $ ATC: num 0
#  $ ATT: num 0
#  $ ATG: num 1
#  $ ACA: num 0
#  $ ACC: num 0
#  $ ACG: num 0
# ...snip...
#  $ TAT: num 0
#  $ TAA: num 0
#  $ TAG: num 0
#  $ TGC: num 0.5
#  $ TGT: num 0.5
#  $ TGA: num 0
#  $ TGG: num 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this help, but what should i do to get answer for just 64 codons. I want to get the percentage among that 64 codons only

Comment: Also suppose there is no TCC codon in an argument then, i want it will show that TCC=0

Comment: For TCC=0, just do `res[is.na(res)]<-0` (if `res` is holding the results). "Just 64 codons”, no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Sir for example if we have our argument like ATGATAATCATT then we get a table which says thats ATG codes for M and percentage is ! and ATA, ATC, ATT codes for I and its percentage is  0.3 percent and rest of the 64 lists of codons shows 0 because there is no other codons in an argument

Comment: sir, if my argument contains 1000 to 10k characters and i want to calculate the count of each 64 codons and then check its percentage and get output in a table of this four column(codons, amino acids for which it codes for and count and percentage) then how can i proceed this problem please guide me in this.

Comment: How could i proceed in solving this?

Comment: Mayank, you asked a question, it was answered in three ways. Now you have another question, and though it is related to the first (because to you it is the next problem you must overcome), it is still different enough from the original to warrant [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). I suggest you start the next question with the `codon` and frequency-finding method you choose (a link to here *plus* the literal values/functions), and then include what you've tried so far to get `table` or `xtabs` (etc) to give you what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Also thank you for your efforts

Answer (score 2):

A slightly different path leads to this solution:

```
f0 <- function(dna, weight) {
    codons <- regmatches(dna, gregexpr("[ATGC]{3}", dna))
    tibble(id = seq_along(codons), codons = codons) %>%
        unnest() %>%
        mutate(weight = as.vector(wt[codons]))
}
```

First, `codon` is just a named vector, not list; here are the weights

```
codon <- unlist(codon)
weight <- setNames(1 / table(codon)[codon], names(codon))
```

Second, probably there is a vector of DNA sequences, rather than one.

```
dna <- c("ATGTGTTGCTGG", "GGTCGTTGTGTA")
```

To develop the solution, codons can be found by searching for any nucleotide `[ACGT]` repeated `{3}` times

```
codons <- regmatches(dna, gregexpr("[ATGC]{3}", dna))
```

It seems like it is then convenient to do operations in the tidyverse, creating a tibble (data.frame) where `id` indicates which sequence the codon is from

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tibble(id = seq_along(codons), codon = codons) %>% unnest()
```

and then add the weights

```
tbl <- mutate(tbl, weight = as.vector(weight[codon]))
```

so we have

```
> tbl
# A tibble: 8 x 3
     id codon weight
  <int> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 ATG    1    
2     1 TGT    0.5  
3     1 TGC    0.5  
4     1 TGG    1    
5     2 GGT    0.25 
6     2 CGT    0.167
7     2 TGT    0.5  
8     2 GTA    0.25
```

Standard tidyverse operations could be used for further summary, in particular when the same codon appears multiple times

```
tbl %>% group_by(id, codon) %>%
    summarize(wt = sum(weight))
```